# Submit comment with AJAX without refresh page doesn't work anymore

Tags: jquery, form-submit

Hi I have this code to submit a comment through AJAX and a file php without refreshing the page.
Is used to work but since I changed computer to develop this application I had problem and the code never changed.
Now it either crash Chrome or submit without reach the file comment.php

Here is the JS code

```
    <script src="/js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $("#formcomment").submit(function(){        
        ctask = this.task.value;
        cname = this.usrnm.value;
        cmessage = this.comment.value;
        submitter = this.submitter;
        cty = this.ty.value;
        celem = this.elem.value;
        cusrcd = this.usrcd.value;
        cusrcdauth = this.usrcdauth;
        val_recaptcha_challenge_field = this.recaptcha_challenge_field.value;
        val_recaptcha_response_field = this.recaptcha_response_field.value;

        if(cname=="" || cmessage=="") { $("#errAll").html('<p>Please don\'t leave the requierd fields.</p>');  }

        $.post("/comment.php", {task: ctask, usrnm: cname, comment: cmessage, ty: cty, elem: celem, recaptcha_challenge_field:val_recaptcha_challenge_field, recaptcha_response_field:val_recaptcha_response_field, usrcd: cusrcd, usrcdauth: cusrcdauth}, function(data){
            if(data=='0') { $("#errAll").html('<p>Please don\'t leave the requierd fields.</p>'); }
            else if (data=='1') {$("#errAll").html('<p>The reCAPTCHA wasn\'t entered correctly. Try it again.</p>'); }
            else if (data=='2') {$("#errAll").html('<p>Username must contain 6 to 20 characters.</p>'); }
            else { 
                submitter.value="Comment posted"; 
                submitter.disabled=true; 
                $('#listcom').prepend(data); 
                $("#errAll").html('');
                window.location.hash = "#comments";
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
   </script>
```

And the Form in the page

```
   <form class="well" method="post" id="formcomment"> 
    <input type="hidden" id="ty" name="ty" value="stg" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="elem" name="elem" value="13" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="task" id="task" value="addComments" /> 
    <input type="hidden" name="usrcdauth" id="usrcdauth" value="yudtjnisifwndyubleedbtisngvxlj" /> 

    <label>Username</label> 
    <input value="" type="text" id="usrnm" name="usrnm" maxlength="20" class="span3" /> 
    <input type="hidden" id="usrcd" name="usrcd" value="" /> 

    <label>Message</label> 
    <textarea id="comment" name="comment" rows="5" cols="150" class="span7"></textarea> 


    <div style="margin: 15px 0;"><input type="submit" id="submitter" name="submitter" value="Add Comment" class="btn" /></div> 
    <div id="errAll"></div> 
   </form>
```

Comment: What type of computer was the before and after? Did you change OS flavors? Windows to Linux?

Comment: Tip: Use Firebug (Chrome or Firefox) or the built-in Chrome Developer Tools->JS Console to detect JS errors and warnings like 404's, etc.

Comment: I couldn't figure out the problem but I deleted the files and then create a new one and everything works perfectly. I have no idea why

Answer (score 0):

It might sound silly but have you installed a php server like xammp on the new computer? If so make sure the files are in the same directory and maybe try to remove the "/" before comment.php. I didn't go in detail through your code but I think since it worked before; this might be the case.